# How to install boxIcons for an Angular/SCSS project?

Tags: angular, sass, npm-install

For an Angular/SCSS project, I need to install boxicons.

Here is the procedure:

1/ I enter the next command

```
npm install boxicons --save
```

2/ Boxicons is installed

[image]

The problem is that the folder is en CSS, how to get the SCSS version?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do, is add the `boxicons.min.css` to the `angular.json` file, in the below location.

```
 "architect": {
            "build": {
                "options": {
                    "styles": [
                       "node_modules/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css",
                    ],
               }
                ....
```

---

After that all the box icons classes will be available inside the scss files you are using in your project. Since the owner has not provided scss, you need to raise a enhancement on the github page of the author of boxicons!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem is that the `boxicons.min.css` file is in `CSS` format, so it doesn't work. Can we turn it into SCSS?

Comment: @juliette It should be done by the creator, what is you end goal converting it to scss, `css or scss` format should not be big deal right?

Comment: In fact, I want to have the file in SCSS, but I'm a beginner.

Comment: @juliette try to use the classes using this method, it won't impact your development, converting css to scss is too tedious and long

Comment: I converted CSS to SCSS and it works. I will keep this method and contact the author of boxicons for a SCSS version. Thanks a lot for your help. The most important thing is that it works. :-)

Comment: How should I close the post? hahaha